# Help with a Tiny Sized Melee Fighter in Pathfinder

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, unarmed-combat, mythic-adventures

I'm involved in a fairly unusual campaign. I'm trying to build a tiny sized (faerie dragon) unarmed melee fighter, and I'm just looking or anything I can do to increase DPS. The character will be Level 18 and Mythic 6.

I was asked to rebuild a character from top to bottom by my GM. The only restriction was that the character follow the same concept as the original. So, I have to keep race and unarmed combat.It's optional, but it's kind of hard to pass up the opportunity.

I don't have any particular attachment to a class, although the character was originally a Monk/Lore Warden Fighter/Soul Hunter Stalker (from Path of War). I have to stay Chaotic Neutral as well, although with the Mythic thrown in and Beyond Morality, that's not a huge issue.

Comment: This might be a little too broad.  Can you be more specific?  IE - what classes do you have in mind?  Do you have a magic item budget?  Why unarmed?  Is that a restriction from the DM or from you?  Would you accept say claws?  Would you accept enlargement?

Comment: Added a few details for clarity.

Comment: What issues did your DM have with your previous build?

Comment: At 18th level people have level 9 spells.  Are you playing in a lower level campaign where you've been given extra levels as compensation for melee becoming irrelevant or are you asking how to make your tiny unarmed melee combatant on par with equal-levelled spellcasters?

Comment: Neither. Just trying to make the most effective tiny unarmed combatant I can :-)

Comment: You should have a plan about how to defend yourself from combat maneuvers. Being tiny and weak probably means you have a rather low CMD.

Comment: @Umbranus The good news is that a lot of combat maneuvers shouldn't affect him. He can't be disarmed or sundered because he doesn't use weapons (though I'm actually not sure what the rules say about attempting to sever an arm), and he probably can't be tripped because fairie dragons fly. Bull rushing, grappling, and dirty tricks would still affect him, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought is to use a build where the damage comes primarily from something other than normal physical attributes. Some possibilities are...

### Esoteric Magus

This might not fit with your picture of the character or what your DM has in mind, but have you considered the Esoteric Magus archetype from Occult Adventures? It's basically a magus with unarmed strikes like a monk. That would provide a lot of damage from magic, plus all of the other nice spells that magi can cast.

### Unarmed Unchained Rogue/Ninja

An unchained rogue or ninja with the Improved Unarmed Strike feat would gain most of their damage from sneak attacks. The unchained rogue offers Finesse Training and Debilitating Strike, while the ninja offers the ability to gain an additional attack by expending ki.

### Monk/Unchained Rogue

A monk could take 3 levels of unchained rogue to gain Finesse Training and 2d6 sneak attack, with the possibility of taking the Accomplished Sneak Attacker feat from the Dirty Tactics Toolbox to bump that up to 3d6 sneak attack (the feat doesn't say you can take it multiple times, though your DM might allow that). This is especially nice because sneak attack combines well with the monk's Stunning Fist.

Comment: I rather love this idea, but I'm not sure my GM would let me get away with it. I'll run it past him.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you won't have the large crit range that most magi aim for (or at least, I don't know of a way to do it to the same extent you can with a scimitar).

Comment: K, I think I'm going with the Monk/UCRogue combo. It's closest in theme to the original build, and it looks like fun. WIS to AC is a great bonus, too.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with this, ends up being your size. The increase to dex, attacks, and AC is nice, but your damage drops horrifically.

Monk's have increasing unarmed strike damage, so while not great damage, its much better than what you would be dealing. Also look into seeing if you are allowed to take superior weapon fineness which allows you to add dex to damage.

There is magic that can help, such as strong jaw, it increases your damage die by 2 steps (which due to your size isnt as helpful as it normally is).

Power attack feat is also something you can use to increase your damage.

An amulet of mighty fists can be enchanted to have weapon enhancement properties, so adding flaming would give you 1d6 fire and not be affected by your size.

Comment: Strong jaw and such are really terrible for someone who is that small and who will take his damage from something else that the die of the weapon.